# how to get only today emails - Gmail + Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-api

In my Google Script I want to parse only email from today + with a certain label.

1. solution using Gmail.Users.Messages.list()

I found out that possible solution is to use search query. Today is `20.10.2020` and this search query `after:2020/10/20 before:2020/10/22`  returns only emails from today. If I use this solution the I do not know how to pass the right dates to the query.

2. solution using GmailApp.getUserLabelByName()

I would prefer to use `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName()` not `Gmail.Users.Messages.list()` so I can work with threads not messages. I understand correcly how the two method work.

Comment: How about Utilities.formatDate()-https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)

Comment: can formatDate add a number to a date?

Comment: Be more specific

Comment: O need to add 2 to the current date to prepare the query. Because of the date it is not just simple adding. --- it looks like @Marios answered that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- As also [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) suggested, you can construct the dates and
  convert them to the desired format by using the [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) class.
- Then, you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct the query argument and pass all the date and label variables to the string object.
- [getSpreadsheetTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone) is used to get the time zone of the spreadsheet. You can replace that with your actual `GMT`, for example:

  ```
  const td = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+1', "yyyy/MM/dd");
  const td_2 = Utilities.formatDate(today_2, 'GMT+1', "yyyy/MM/dd");
  ```

---

### Solution that uses the time zone of the spreadsheet:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const today = new Date();
  const today_2 = new Date();
  today_2.setDate(new Date().getDate()+2);
  const td = Utilities.formatDate(today, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
  const td_2 = Utilities.formatDate(today_2, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
  const mylabel = 'unread';
  
  const queryString = `label: ${mylabel} after: ${td} before: ${td_2}`;
  const threads = GmailApp.search(queryString); 

}
```

---

### Solution with custom timezone:

Adjust `GMT+1` to your own/desired timezone.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const today = new Date();
  const today_2 = new Date();
  today_2.setDate(new Date().getDate()+2);
  const td = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+1', "yyyy/MM/dd");
  const td_2 = Utilities.formatDate(today_2, 'GMT+1', "yyyy/MM/dd");
  const mylabel = 'unread';
  
  const queryString = `label: ${mylabel} after: ${td} before: ${td_2}`;
  Logger.log(queryString); // check the output in the View -> Logs
  const threads = GmailApp.search(queryString); // GmailThread[] — an array of Gmail threads matching this query
}
```

Comment: I don not understand what `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` goes. Do I need to create some temporary spreadsheet for the calculation or ... ?

Comment: @Radek check my updated answer. You can replace that part with your own timezone.

Comment: are you saying that the result of the search is array of threads? That would completely answered my problem I wanted to solve here. Let me check and then I accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Radek yes it is an array of threads. Hence the name `threads` in the code.

Comment: I am sure it has nothing to do with your code but running the final query in the script and inside Gmail web interface gives me different result. There is one email that arrive 0:49am that the script does not pick up. Any idea? Fiddling with GMT did not help.

Comment: @Radek Please check the output of the `queryString` to make sure that it is the query string you expect. I am feeling that you have set up the timezone wrongly and you don't get the right dates. But in order to be sure about that we need to see what `queryString` returns. Please check my second answer how to log it.

Comment: I am using the string the script generated - see https://i.imgur.com/sHiKug8.png

Comment: @Radek we are using the label: unread in this example. Are you sure the email you are not getting is unread?

Comment: @Radek also I see in your screenshot that you are getting 21 and 22 as days but you should get 21 and 23. So please, check again if you have put the correct timezone. Google what is the timezone of your place and change it accordingly.

Comment: I updated the script so the result is 22 not 23. It not necessary to use 23.10.2020. Check the screenshot the query is the same. https://i.imgur.com/9ufaTas.png the very last email is the trouble some. It is not about your code. Just wonder if you can help me to debug it.

Comment: @Radek that is very weird. It is either a bug or something else which unfortunately I can not reproduce myself. :( sorry

Comment: I will test tomorrow with different date. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Radek glad I helped. Let's see if the bug will persist.

Comment: would you know if there is a way I can report such bug to Google?

Comment: @Radek can you please try one more thing, use this instead: `const threads =GmailApp.search(queryString, 0, 10);` . If this also does not work. Please post a new question so other people might be able to suggest something.

Comment: good suggestion. I created the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468851/google-query-formula-executed-via-google-script-and-web-interface-gives-diffrent

the new search formula, you suggested did not help