# Google query formula executed via Google Script and web interface gives different results

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I needed a solution to my question how to get date of `today and tomorrow` in Google Script. I got it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452745/how-to-get-only-today-emails-gmail-google-script#64453057) While trying to understand the code provided in the answer I found out that I get different result from the script and from web interface. The script does not pick up one email, the one that was sent 0:49am. [image] Note that the script gets 6 threads but web interface 7.

Any idea what to do about it? Debug, report?

```
function today_tmp() {
  const today = new Date();
  const today_2 = new Date();
  today_2.setDate(new Date().getDate()+1);
  const td = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+2', "yyyy/MM/dd");
  const td_2 = Utilities.formatDate(today_2, 'GMT+2', "yyyy/MM/dd");
  const mylabel = 'unread';
  const queryString = `label: ${mylabel} after: ${td} before: ${td_2}`;
  const threads = GmailApp.search(queryString); 
  //const threads =GmailApp.search(queryString, 0, 10);  // this one did not work
  Logger.log(queryString);
  Logger.log(threads.length);
  for (var t in threads) {
    Logger.log(threads[t].getMessages()[0].getSubject());    
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
GMT+1 is set up in Project Properties. I tried to change GMT+1 in the code but it has no effect for the issue. I live in Prague time zone.

`getDate()` for the "missing" message is `Wed Oct 21 00:49:09 GMT+02:00 2020` and today is Oct 21.

Comment: What time zone does your Project Properties have listed?

Comment: `GMT+1` is in Project Properties. I tried to change GMT+1 in the code but it has no effect for the issue.

Comment: And as far as Debug messages, perhaps setting `today` to -1 day for debug and  printing `message.getDate()` for each message would help narrow down the issue. This really looks like some issue with timezones somewhere.

Comment: getDate() for the "missing" message is `Wed Oct 21 00:49:09 GMT+02:00 2020`

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12329972/1708751

Comment: hm, probably related but I do not see nor explanation or solution. I guess for me it would be to use `today-1` as you suggested for debugging. But it seems to me that everything is fine. The timezone for the message is GMT+2 and my timezone is GMT+1 but because of time saving it is GMT+2.

Comment: To elaborate on my referral, you could perform your searches based on UTC timestamp instead of a timezone-ambiguous `GmailApp.search` from a provided date.

Comment: @SunnyPatel, the code (after some modification) works. It is still using `GmailApp.search` but it works. Could you explain? Do you want to create an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error it seems as if `GmailApp.search` isn't consistent with timezone information (Script Project Properties vs. `GmailApp` API commands) when searching by dates alone. If you need to be very specific to capture on date boundaries based on your timezone, you should pass that information in as timestamp values.

```js
const mylabel = 'unread';
const morning = new Date();
morning.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);  // Set date to midnight of current day
const night = new Date();
night.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0); // Set end date to future midnight of current day

const queryString = `label: ${mylabel} newer:${morning.getTime()/1000} older:${night.getTime()/1000}`;
const threads = GmailApp.search(queryString);
```

Comment: how can I set morning date to -1 hour of midnight of current day? To make sure That I do not miss any emails that might arrive in between processing around midnight?

Comment: @Radek Something along the lines of: `morning.setHours(-1);`